# how can a tcp socket read call never return

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server, buffer

A client has reported an error I fail to comprehend. A TCP based client is connected to the server from which it receives data, rarely sending anything. Usually everything works fine, but once in a blue moon a situation like this occurs:

- server sends some data
- client receives the data
- client is processing the data
- ... and in the meantime server sends a lot more data
- client finishes processing
- client attempts to read the data from socket
- client forever hangs on a first read() statement after processing
- server closes the connection
- client still hangs

Here is how the tcp connection is established (stripped of all logs, return checks etc)

```
ret = inet_pton(AF_INET, conn->address, &addr.sin_addr);
addr.sin_port        = htons(conn->port); /* Server port */
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

And here is the read wrapper:

```
int32_t _readn ( int fd, uint8_t *vptr, int32_t n )
{
  int32_t  nleft;
  int32_t  nread;
  uint8_t*     ptr;

  ptr = vptr;
  nleft = n;
  while (nleft > 0) {
    if ((nread = read (fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
      if (errno == EINTR) {
        nread = 0;
      } else {
        return E_NETWORK_ERROR;
      }
    } else if ( nread == 0 ) {
      break;
    }
    nleft -= nread;
    ptr   += nread;
  }
  return  (n-nleft);
}
```

Is it possible for the read call to block for ever, even after the connection is closed?

Is there some kind of tricky error in my wrapper that I didn't notice that may cause this? Should I set some flags for the socket on connection?

Comment: Is there a reason of why to not use it non-blocking and put like a `select` on the fd instead?

Comment: No, there is none. Doing so might be a solution. There are a few other way I can think of that would be a good workaround. But I want to know the source of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is if there is no data to read the read will block. E.g. if there are fewer than the expected n bytes written. This is known as a blocking read.

To discover whether there is data, use `select` as Jite says.

Finally you may have a firewall dropping a live connection. Some firewalls are configured to cut connections which have been open for longer than a given time, e.g. 30 minutes. Probably this is not what you have however.

Comment: No data=block is not the source - it's the result. The source remains undiscovered.

Comment: @DariuszWawer Where do you get `n` from? How do you know how many bytes are expected?

Comment: the application layer protocol provides that information. I first read 3 common-for-all-messages header bytes, based on which I decide how much data to read.

Comment: @DariuszWawer, Is the number correct? Also, how do you know if there is even the three header bytes? Is there a special "end of stream" message, or does it just stop sending? Psychic debugging tells me the server is probably waiting for a reply message before sending more data, and somehow your application level protocol has got desynchronised, so the client is waiting for further data which isn't coming. So I suggest looking at the actual data - is it actually a complete message? Is the expected length correct?

Comment: If there are no meaningful messages, a heartbit is sent every two seconds. I doublechecked the amount of data I expect with the documentation. It is ok. Earlier on the same messages with the same length were received correctly.

Comment: How about other debugging. You have established with a _strace_ or debugger that it is the `read()` where the client blocks? Have you checked with _ss_ or similar socket tool to see if the Recv-Q has data when the client blocks?

Comment: @DariuszWawer, does the server ever wait for a message from the client? Have you tried Network Monitor or WireShark to verify the data you expect was actually sent?

Comment: I didn't and I can't do it - it's not my environment.
An update: right now I am leaning towards this answer: the server is faulty. When an incomplete write occurs the server stops sending data in the middle of a message. I can't verify it though, I don't have the server code (or even a server instance...).

Comment: @DariuszWawer, you can run Network Monitor on your own machine, and see if the data arrives.

Comment: @Ben I accepted your answer since that is what I ended up doing. It did not fix the problem, but it is a workaround. Posted the code in case anyone someday needs it.

Comment: This is all correct except for the 'e.g. if there are fewer than the expected `n` bytes written' part. It only takes one byte to unblock a `recv()`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a select-based function to check if data is available.

While the reason behind the mysterious data loss is still unknown (no server error convirmed), this seems to do the trick:

```
int32_t isReadDataAvailableOnSocket ( int sock, uint32_t waitTimeUs )
{
  fd_set fds;
  int16_t ret = 0;
  struct timeval timeout;
  struct timeval* timeoutPtr = NULL;

  if (waitTimeUs>0) {
    timeout.tv_sec = waitTimeUs / 1000000;
    timeout.tv_usec = waitTimeUs % 1000000;
    timeoutPtr = &timeout;
  }

  FD_ZERO ( &fds );
  FD_SET ( sock, &fds );

  ret = select ( sock+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, timeoutPtr );
  if (ret == -1) {
    WARN("select failed for udp socket=[%d]", sock);
    return E_NETWORK_ERROR;
  }
  if ( ! FD_ISSET(sock, &fds) )
  {
    return E_NO_DATA;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Networks lose data. TCP counters this using the “shout it over and over until it arrives” approach, but that can take an unbounded amount of time to succeed if the network is very unhappy…

Comment: @DonalFellows It isn't unbounded. The attempts will timeout and fail eventually.

Comment: The send side will fail. The receive side will continue waiting forever.